# Variation of Pulse width with center frequency in Pulse Compression technique

Tags: signal-analysis, convolution, time-frequency

Assume a chirp with BW = 1 Hz (frequency range 0-1 Hz) for a period of 700 sec. The pulse compression technique (obtained through auto correlation function) applied on the chirp  generates a pulse with the main lobe width of 1.0 sec.
However, on changing the frequency range to 1-2 Hz ( the BW is same) , the width of the main lobe of the generated pulse changes to 0.6. The image shows [image: the compressed pulse obtained from two different chirps at 0-1 Hz and 1-2 Hz frequency range,respectively]

I would like to know the reason behind this. Theoretically, the width of the main pulse is dependent only on the BW. (=1/2BW)

Comment: You might indicate where you got the plot from. It appears that the above is a plot of the chirp after matched filtering, correct?

Comment: Yes, the plot is y = xcorr (chirp,chirp).(Normalized and absolute value)